# How to convert a string into a list/tuple without losing the type of the values in the string?

Tags: python, python-3.x

If i have

```
a = "3.14, ABCF , 2.16"
```

and type(a) returns "str"

how may i convert this into a list or tuple and keep the type integrity of elements inside.(ex: running through the collection and check type should return float, string, float, respectively)

Comment: What type integrity? All you have is a `string` there are no other types here

Comment: Ah thank you, that's something i had a question about. Would I be able to do something like **"{0}, {1}, {2}".format(3.14,"ABCF", 2.16)** instead? or is there any other way i could do so?

Comment: That creates a `string` with the given values. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve here. A string is a string, it doesn't have any other types

Comment: Thank you, I think you have answered my question. I seemed to have a lapse in my understanding!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this using regular expression

```
import re
a = "3.14, ABCF , 2.16 , 9"
b=a.split(",")  #break string
for c in b:
    x=c.strip() # removes whitespace character
    if x.isdigit(): #return bool value
        print("int")
    elif bool(re.search('[a-zA-Z]+', x)):
        print("string")
    elif bool(re.search('[0-9.]+', x)):
        print("float")
```

**OUTPUT :**

```
float
string
float
int
```

**OR**

By using python `ast` library

```
from ast import literal_eval

def get_type(data):
    try:
        return type(literal_eval(data))
    except (ValueError, SyntaxError):
        # A string, so return str
        return str

a = "3.14, ABCF , 2.16 , 9, True"
b=a.split(",")
for c in b:
    x=c.strip()
    print(get_type(x))
```

**OUTPUT:**

```
<class 'float'>
<class 'str'>
<class 'float'>
<class 'int'>
<class 'bool'>
```

Comment: Why are you casting `x.isdigit()` to a `bool`? It already returns that. Also the regular expressions don't actually guarantee any kind of type safety, you just assume that strings conforming to that schema are of that type

Comment: Thanks @UnholySheep, i have updated previous code and i have added another type of example to do same.